# MySQL Command in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, sql

So, I have an iOS App that need to do a MySQL command:

```
INSERT INTO SeB
VALUES ('123123','321321')
```

I don't know how to do this command with **Objective-C**. Any tips?

PS: The database is [online](http://dbmy0055.whservidor.com/).

**Thanks a lot!!!**
Alberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to open up a MySQL database on the Internet like this, for security reasons.

Instead, you should set up some kind of web server that would accept requests and then connect to the database.

For example, your iOS app would send a regular HTTP request to your server (like `http://example.com/request/?data1=123123&data2=321321`; the web server script would then be able to check the input and then write to the database.

There are plenty of options for the web site -- PHP, Perl, ASP, Ruby, etc.

Comment: Wow! So simple! =D Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet is to send the data that you need to insert via a web request (as either a JSON object or SOAP).  PHP is built perfectly to handle those kinds of data structures and interact with a MySQL (hence the LAMP acronym).

Comment: Do you have a tutorial for this? Is the first time I have used it, so, I'm a little lost. =S Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertoSantos I don't know of any online tutorials, but [link this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596157142.do) is what helped me understand php and how it interacts with MySQL.